# Disabling android CoordinatorLayout scrolling behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

When adding **scrolling behaviour** to a layout with **coordinatorLayout** like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the mainContent is the part that matters.

The real layout will be inflated inside this container.

Imagining my `View` consists of a `RecyclerView`, and a fixed layout at the bottom of the screen.

Does someone know a way to remove the *scrolling behavior* of the bottom fixed layout and keep the `RecyclerView`-`Toolbar`-hide behaviour?

Comment: You need to remove that fixed layout's scrolling at the bottom? and what do you mean by: `keep the RecyclerView-Toolbar-hide behaviour` please make it clear to underestand what you mean exactly.

Comment: when i scroll the mainContent, everything will scroll, all child views. I want to exclude the bottom view from scrolling

Comment: meaning, the bottom view will be fixed in the layout (not scrollable) while the recyclerview above it will scroll normally, with the toolbar interactions (recyclerview scroll up, toolbar hide, scroll down, toolbar show). I want to exclude a child view of mainContent from scrolling. is it possible without moving that view outside the scrollable container?

Comment: I don't think so(AFAIK), i believe the first problem is because you have a `RecyclerView` on that `View` and the second one is, Your `FrameLayout` is in the `CoordinatorLayout` Otherwise, you could put the `CoordinatorLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` and then under the `CoordinatorLayout` could be the `View` which it's not scrollable anymore.But, this is for all `Fragment` i guess and not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a 'CoordinatorLayout' the views that scroll must be first and only later the non-scrollable views. I managed to solve the issue by placing my non-scrollable layout outside the 'mainContent', just below it